# Ambiguous positional update operation

Tags: mongodb

I have this collection in MongoDB (version v3.6.3):

```
{
  _id: '1'
  elements:[
    {
      _id: '11'
      status : DRAFT   
    },
    {
      _id: '12'
      status : DRAFT   
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to update the element `11` from job `1` **ONLY IF** the status is `DRAFT`. I've tried this query:

```
db.getCollection('jobs').update(
  {'_id':'1', 'elements._id': '11', 'elements.status': 'DRAFT'},
  {'$set': { 'elements.$.status' : 'APPROVED' } }
)
```

and as result I have:

```
ambiguous positional update operation
```

what is the problem?

---

SOLUTION (thanks @neil-lun)

```
db.getCollection('jobs').update({
  '_id':'1', 
  'elements': {
    '$elemMatch': {
      '_id': '11', 
      'elements.status': 'DRAFT'
    }
  }
},
{'$set': { 'elements.$.status' : 'APPROVED' } })
```

What confused me is that:

```
db.getCollection('jobs').find({
  '_id':'1', 'elements._id': '11', 'elements.status': 'DRAFT'})
```

is a valid query and works fine

Comment: Are you using mongo shell? The _id and element_id are int in documents but passed as a string in the update query.

Comment: @Astro I'm using mongo shell and all my _id are strings

Comment: @Ashish it works fine if i remove one of the conditions on the `elements`, but I need them

Comment: `$elemMatch` is required in order to match "multiple" criteria for array elements. The error is because your conditions match "possibly different" elements of the array by the "dot notation" used. See also [Specify Multiple Conditions for Array Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#specify-multiple-conditions-for-array-of-documents) in the core documentation.

Comment: Then try with `elemMatch`